# Script not working on localhost but works in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

This jsfiddle works http://jsfiddle.net/y913yh4u/2/ but the code saved locally doesn't work https://pastebin.com/rkiDRfFz

using this says that DataTable isn't a function, even though the script is included.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myTable').DataTable();
    });
```

LocalHost:
[image]

JSFIDDLE:
[image]

**Any help would be appericated.**

Comment: Have you linked jQuery on your localhost HTML file? You have specified jQuery on your jsfiddle.

Comment: please share your html code? you missed plugin or your script file url is not correct

Comment: @pc_coder https://pastebin.com/rkiDRfFz

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen - No, it has to be **here, on-site**, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: @Vepthy yes, I have its an exact copy of the jsfiddle

Comment: in your jsfiddle the javascript section shows jquery 1.9.1 loaded, even though your html section is referencing 1.7.1, is it a version issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is attached before the closing body tag.

The browser stops parsing the page when it encounters a script tag. Therefore, so that the user sees the content as early as possible, the connection of scripts is delayed until the very last moment.

Try to do so.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
</head>

<body>

  <table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      ...
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if first line of body or last line of body or in header. Important is correct order of them. U can just try with local html to put it first line of body. You will see it will work %100